# How can I format my data so that I have the corresponding teams with their scores? (Scrapy Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm having trouble formatting my scraped data, any advice on how I could extract my data into four columns (Winning Team, Losing Team, Winning Score, Losing Score)

```
import scrapy


class sportsDataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sportsSite"
    allowed_domains = ["www.espn.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.espn.com/nhl/scoreboard/_/date/20220504"]

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        hockey_score_selector = response.css(".ScoreCell__Team--scoreboard").extract()
        loser_sel = ".ScoreboardScoreCell__Item--loser .ScoreCell__Score::text"
        winner_sel = ".ScoreboardScoreCell__Item--winner .ScoreCell__Score::text"
        team_sel = ".ScoreboardPage .ScoreCell__TeamName--shortDisplayName::text"

        loser_score = response.css(loser_sel).extract()
        winner_score = response.css(winner_sel).extract()
        teams = response.css(team_sel).extract()

        yield {
            'losing score': loser_score,
            'winning score': winner_score,
            'teams': teams
        }
```

This is my current output I get from this code.

```
{'losing score': ['2', '3', '2', '0'], 'winning score': ['5', '5', '6', '6'], 'teams': ['Bruins', 'Hurricanes', 'Lightning', 'Maple Leafs', 'Blues', 'Wild', 'Kings', 'Oilers']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting all the teams at once based on `.ScoreboardPage`, try collecting two sets based on `.ScoreboardScoreCell__Item--loser` and `.ScoreboardScoreCell__Item--winner`. So:

```
    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        hockey_score_selector = response.css(".ScoreCell__Team--scoreboard").extract()
        loser_sel = ".ScoreboardScoreCell__Item--loser .ScoreCell__Score::text"
        winner_sel = ".ScoreboardScoreCell__Item--winner .ScoreCell__Score::text"
        
        # team_sel = ".ScoreboardPage .ScoreCell__TeamName--shortDisplayName::text"
        loser_team_sel = ".ScoreboardScoreCell__Item--loser .ScoreCell__TeamName--shortDisplayName::text"
        winner_team_sel = ".ScoreboardScoreCell__Item--winner .ScoreCell__TeamName--shortDisplayName::text"

        loser_score = response.css(loser_sel).extract()
        winner_score = response.css(winner_sel).extract()

        # teams = response.css(team_sel).extract()
        loser_teams = response.css(loser_team_sel).extract()
        winner_teams = response.css(winner_team_sel).extract()

        yield {
            'losing score': loser_score,
            'winning score': winner_score,
            # 'teams': teams,
            'losing team': loser_teams,
            'winning team': winner_teams
        }
```

Output:

```
{'losing score': ['2', '3', '2', '0'],
 'winning score': ['5', '5', '6', '6'],
 'losing team': ['Bruins', 'Maple Leafs', 'Blues', 'Kings'],
 'winning team': ['Hurricanes', 'Lightning', 'Wild', 'Oilers']}
```

E.g. Bruins lost to Hurricanes, etc.